# finding average, min and max in assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, max, min

I'm having a problem in finding the average, min and max of an array in assembly language. i created a simple array with C++ and created a test.asm file to pass it through. i figured out the average, but now its the min and max i cant seem to figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
int test(int*, int);

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 7;
int arr[SIZE] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

int val = test(arr, SIZE);


cout << "The function test returned: " << val << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is my test.asm that adds all the values and returns 4.

```
.686
.model flat

.code


_test PROC ;named _test because C automatically prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
push ebp
mov ebp,esp ;stack pointer to ebp

mov ebx,[ebp+8] ; address of first array element
mov ecx,[ebp+12]
mov ebp,0
mov edx,0
mov eax,0


loopMe:
cmp ebp,ecx
je allDone


add eax,[ebx+edx]
add edx,4
add ebp,1
jmp loopMe

allDone:
mov edx,0
div ecx

pop ebp
ret
_test ENDP

END
```

I am still trying to figure out how to find the min since the max will be done in a similar way. I assume you use the cmp to compare values but everything i tried so far hasn't been successful. I'm fairly new to assembly language and its hard for me to grasp. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggest writing it in C instead, and looking at the compiler output to see what it does. Then decide whether you actually want to write in assembly.

Comment: Choose a register to hold your min/max, and initialize it with the first array element. Then use the `cmp` instruction to determine whether to replace that value with the current element or not. Simple.

Comment: Do you want to return minimum, maximum and average to calling process? That can be done, as long as values are less than 255 in one 32 bit register, but values greater than that would need additional logic.

Comment: Show what was not successful with your "min" try? Also it's not clear how you want to return 3 values (return is single `int`). And I think it may be good for you to cleanup this average function to the best you can do, verify it works, and post it to codereview site for suggestions, as this can be written a bit more "cleanly", using less registers and instructions (it's easier then to read and debug). Maybe a way for you to ask is to show well commented (high level intention) short asm source, and point out what values/inst. you don't understand, or which part of high-level you can't write.

Comment: BTW, I prefer even test-projects to have API designed in a bit better way than "crash on division by zero" on empty array. Adding one more test+return value is only tad more work, and it's a good practice for you to think about API usage all the time, even when doing only some "learning" tests.

Answer (score 1):

> Any help is appreciated

Ok, so I will show you refactored average function, even if you didn't ask for it directly. :)

Things you can learn from this:

- simplified function prologue/epilogue, when `ebp` is not modified in code
- the input array is of 32b `int` values, so to have correct average you should calculate 64b sum, and do the 64b sum signed division
- subtle "tricks" how to get zero value (`xor`) or how `inc` is +1 to value (lowering code size)
- handling zero sized array by returning fake average `0` (no crash)
- addition of two 64b values composed from 32b registers/instructions
- counting human "index" (+1 => direct cmp with `size` possible), yet addressing 32b values (usage of `*4` in addressing)
- renamed to `getAverage`

BTW, this is not optimized for performance, I tried to keep the source "simple", so it's easy to read and understand what is it doing.

```
_getAverage PROC
    ; avoiding `ebp` usage, so no need to save/set it
    mov   ebx,[esp+4]   ; address of first array element
    mov   ecx,[esp+8]   ; size of array
    xor   esi,esi       ; array index 0
    ; 64b sum (edx:eax) = 0
    xor   eax,eax
    cdq
    ; test for invalid input (zero sized array)
    jecxz zeroSizeArray ; arguments validation, returns 0 for 0 size

    ; here "0 < size", so no "index < size" test needed for first element
    ; "do { ... } while(index < size);" loop variant

sumLoop:
    ; extend value from array[esi] to 64b (edi is upper 32b)
    mov   edi,[ebx+esi*4]
    sar   edi,31
    ; edx:eax += edi:array[esi]  (64b array value added to 64b sum)
    add   eax,[ebx+esi*4]
    adc   edx,edi
    ; next index and loop while index < size
    inc   esi
    cmp   esi,ecx
    jb    sumLoop

    ; divide the 64b sum of integers by "size" to get average value
    idiv  ecx           ; signed (!) division (input array is signed "int")
    ; can't overflow (Divide-error), as the sum value was accumulated
    ; from 32b values only, so EAX contains full correct result
zeroSizeArray:
    ret
_getAverage ENDP
```

Comment: Nice, good thinking that you can use idiv without risk of overflow.  I might have used CDQ inside the loop (to load each array element only once into EAX), but that would require two MOV instructions after the loop.  Two memory refs to the same location isn't bad here (I don't think it hurts readability or understandability, which is what you're going for).  Of course, if I cared about speed, I'd use PADDQ after SSE4 PMOVZX, or manually sign-extend with SSE2 (probably PSRAD and PUNPCKL/HDQ with the original).